# Why use stick tables in HAProxy?

Tags: haproxy

What is the purpose of HAProxy stick tables? What are the cases using them and why are they important?

I'm looking for some one to explain why (not how), the docs aren't helpful in this case. If anybody can point me to any additional information, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 6):

The biggest use case for using sticky connections is if your backend servers don't share state information with each other. So a use case might be if the app server writes session data to local disk and not like a database like memcache.

Another use case would be like you had a site that allowed image uploads but the processing took place on the same server on another page load when a user hit next. This way it would stay on the same backend server since the backend server's don't share state.

Comment: Even when they do share state it is advantageous to stick to a specific backend unless it becomes unavailable to make best use of caching.

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, this setting is meant to be use when you want a connection to be load balanced between nodes but you want the connection to stay on the node it goes to for a timeframe you configure.

So if I ask google.com and haproxy send me to web25.google.local than I will always be redirect to this server until the timeframe timeout.

http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html#stick-table